# Genetic Algorithm - Order of variables in a chromosome

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, evolutionary-algorithm, jgap

Using the concept of crossover points, the order of variables in a chromosome does seem to matter: Variables directly next to each other will have a higher chance to remain together in the children's chromosomes compared to variables far away from each other. What does this mean for my gene encoding? How should I order variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can improve a crossover little. You may shuffle parents, and than make crossover. You must applied on child an inversion process to shuffling. With this procedure, the genes far from each other may be together in child and genes next to each other do not have lay next to each other in child.

Comment: Similar results can be achieved with multiple-points crossover operation.